# What is the origin of 'common or garden'?

Tags: etymology, idioms

Why do we speak, for example, of a 'common or garden' bicycle, meaning one that simply does the job of a bicycle without alloy wheels, Sir Bradley Wiggins pedals or any other bells and whistles.

'Common or garden' means much the same thing as 'bog standard' and can apply to anything animate or inanimate.

**Edit 28/7/15**

The **OED entry** says.

> d.  passing into adj., in the slang phr. common or garden, a jocular substitute for ‘common’, ‘ordinary’.
>
> [1657   W. Coles Adam in Eden xxix. 59   *But the Common or Garden Nightshade is not dangerous*.]
>
> 1892   Autobiog. Eng. Gamekeeper (J. Wilkins) 67   *It was as large as a common—or garden—hen.*
>
> 1896   Daily News 16 Oct. 3/4   *Such common or garden proceedings not being to the taste of Noa.*
>
> 1897   Westm. Gaz. 4 Aug. 8/2,   *I have—to make use of a common or garden expression—been ‘rushed’ in this matter.*

Comment: OED's first citation is *[1657   W. Coles Adam in Eden xxix. 59   But the Common or Garden Nightshade is not dangerous.]* I assume they put that one in brackets because it may *not* exactly reflect the modern idiomatic usage, which is next cited in *1892   Autobiog. Eng. Gamekeeper (J. Wilkins) 67   It was as large as a **common — or garden** — hen.* Really, *garden* here just means *domestic, home-grown* (as opposed to *professional*).

Comment: When it comes to [*run-of-the-mill whatzitses*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/garden-variety), I’ve certainly heard *a common whatzit*, and I’ve heard *a garden-variety whatzit*, and I’ve heard *a bog-standard whatzit*, but I’m not sure that I’ve particularly noticed *a **common-or-garden** whatzit* as a unit.

Comment: @tchrist: Interesting. It's a "common as muck" usage in the UK. [Prevalence values from NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=common+or+garden&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccommon%20or%20garden%3B%2Cc0) suggest it's at least 2-3 times more common in the UK than the US.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I’m thinking that *garden* might simply be the common name of the [zillions of taxonomic binomials whose species is *sativus/sativa/sativum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sativa).

Comment: @tchrist: I'm thinking it's ironic that ***garden peas*** are actually quite upmarket compared to *marrowfat/mushy peas* (the poor British Northerner's version of guacamole :). But personally I wouldn't sully my knife with anything less than [petits pois](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/petits+pois).

Comment: @Fumble Fingers My nine-year-old Lancastrian grandson would be disgusted with you. He has already clocked the fact that you can't be a genuine working-class Mancunian without predilection for a cup o'tea, bacon sani, mushy peas and the Daily Mirror.

Comment: I would think _common_ comes from _common_ meaning _open land for public use_ e.g. Wimbledon common, as opposed to farmed land for specific use and _garden_ from well _garden_ really. The key point being it's not something that needs to be tended or forced to grow, your basic _common or garden_ thing.

Comment: @Frank Interesting thought, especially since the first two examples in the OED refer to plants.

Comment: @WS2: The last time I was in Manchester I couldn't believe how swanky the bars down by the canal were. Mind you, I was visiting a couple of gays, and in my experience they do tend to favour a better class of hostelry. Note that OED's second citation is for a ***hen***, not a plant. Their next two (1896, 1897) are for *[court] proceedings* and *[idiomatic] expressions*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I added the American garden variety and common as dirt to your Ngram, changed it to English, and found garden variety the most common. I suspect it's picking up the common or garden variety ending from AmE. I agree with you re: petit pois. I had my first ever mashed peas in London earlier this month. I was amused. Is it so you don't have to chase them all over your plate?

Comment: @medica There is even a Wiki entry on mushy peas - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mushy_peas

Comment: @WS2 - fascinating!

Comment: @FumbleFingers There is plenty that is swanky in Manchester, but as well as being 'the capital of the north' it remains the capital of working-class Britain, with towering civic figures such as Hazel Blears!

Comment: @medica: [I eat my peas with honey;
I've done it all my life.
It makes the peas taste funny,
But it keeps them on the knife.](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/171639) And like it says [here](http://restaurant-ingthroughhistory.com/2011/05/08/etiquette-violations-eating-off-your-knife/), *The only item one should eat with a knife are English peas*.

Comment: @medica They are known as *mushy peas*. If you called them 'mashed peas' in a Manchester chippy, they would assume you were some affected bourgeois twit from somewhere south of the River Trent!

Comment: @WS2 - I didn't call them anything. I don't usually talk to my food.

Comment: An American (i.e., someone from the USA) would never say "common or garden", but might say "common" or even "garden variety" to mean everyday or unexceptional.

Comment: I've always seen it as a witty derivation from a pair of non-Linnaean botanical or ornithological synonyms, the common/garden X. // From [this list courtesy of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_birds_by_common_name), I'd say no bird-name synonyms can be the explanation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The derivation of the phrase obviously *does* have something to do with gardening, or more precisely, agriculture. Its original meaning, as has already been said, relates to the type of plant, fruit or vegetable which is found frequently in gardens or on "commons". (Historically, "commons" were the large patches of grass or woodland that ancient rural villages designated as being for the use of the community as a whole.) If such a plant is found growing in "the common or garden" it is likely to be unexceptional because of its abundance. The phrase has since come to be applied to anything that is common or unexceptional.
(I was going to say "run of the mill" but that would be opening a whole new bag of worms, to coin a phrase).

Comment: `bag of worms` - I think you meant "kettle of badgers"...?

Comment: I like "run of the mill" as its more catchy. Appreciated for bringing that up.

Answer (score 5):

I always assumed it came from the way we describe species of animals or plants. We call lots of abundant species the 'common ____', just a quick google search throws up the common shrew, the common vole, the common pheasant, to dissociate them from the less common species such as the water vole, the pygmy shrew and the golden pheasant.

The term garden is used similarly in colloquial language, especially for plats. As someone said earlier you can call a common rose a garden rose to distinguish it from a highly cultivated and rare species more likely to be found in some botanical garden.

So the term 'common or garden _____' just comes from these phrases used about animals and plants, and was just applied humorously to other objects, such as a common or garden bicycle to distinguish it from a racing bike or a BMX.

Answer (score 3):

It means that it is *no frills* and generally unremarkable, in that it is easy to come by and not in any way fancy.

Think of the roses you may grow in your backyard- they are pretty common and wouldn't likely win a gardening competition; they simply aren't special.  That said, if you were to mention roses, most everyone would be familiar enough with the flower to know what you are talking about.  You would have yourself some *garden variety* roses.

Comment: I don't think you grasp the point at all. The term *common or garden* is applied to everyday objects etc, which need have nothing whatever to do with gardens or gardening.

Comment: The point is a no-frills and unremarkable item is said to be 'garden variety' owing to a metaphorical analogy to plants.

Answer (score 0):

The early botany books referred to "common or garden" species. A species might be common, but not right in a garden. One which is common or garden would be something like a primrose, and the phrase means exactly what it says - nothing to do with commons or cricket pitches or whatever.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The accepted answer at this point is that of @Nick, who has given a similar answer to yours. However you have specifically referred to "early botany books". Do you have any examples of any you can quote from?

Answer (score -3):

I think you are all a little off the mark with respect to the term itself. Firstly, it is "common o' garden" and not common or garden. The truncation (o' ) means of. The phrase is similar to "common o' salt", whic is also erroneously stated as common assault, which is a completely different concept.
Both common o' garden and common o' salt have the same connotation: something that can be found in abundance - as in salt- or in every garden.

Comment: Well, I typed in to Google, "common o' salt" and received the response: "It looks like there aren't many great matches for your search" Surely, in "common o' salt," the o' would be "as"... Can you please give some evidence to support your claim?

Comment: This would benefit from having a source for the "common o' garden" suggestion.